# How to find queries in SQL that belong to a batchjob?

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am troubleshooting a long running batchjob in AX2012 R3.  I am trying to connect the dots: I can see the batchjob defined in the Dynamics database, table "batchjob".  Now I want to find out what's inside the batchjob, so I can see which queries belong to that batchjob when running SQL Profiler. Where can I see this, except of course in AOS/AOT, which I do not have access to?  Is this job defined in some table? Anything will help, even if it's only the tables that are touched by the job.

I already ran SSMS and SQL Profiler, but there's such a lot going on, that I would like to focus on where the pain is. It's just that I'd like to focus on that one batch for now.

Comment: The connection string has an [Application Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring) property. You can see (filter on) that value in Profiler - would that help?

Comment: Use extended events to capture query being executed - especially if using a production system

Comment: This question reads like a SQL dev trying to understand the queries that `x++` code produces. If that's correct, you really should just start by digging into the code a bit and it should be more straightforward via the AOT, which I realize you don't have access to. Batch jobs don't necessarily all have queries. They're potentially a hybrid collection of many activities, which may include various queries. The best approach usually is to start with a developer investigating the code.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes, of course AOT would be the way to go.  I forwarded a link to the team to get more info via AOT.